# Is it possible to create Azure event hub names if not found using .Net Core

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-eventhub

I am looking for a solution to implement creating an Azure event hub name in .Net Core 3.1 If the event hub is not found when we add events assuming the event hub namespace has already been created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible in a direct manner using the packages, but can be achieve this , if you  look at the backend code on Github,

```cs
// Create namespace
var namespaceName = "<populate some unique namespace>";
Console.WriteLine($"Creating namespace... {namespaceName}");
await ehClient.Namespaces.CreateOrUpdateAsync(resourceGroupName, namespaceName, namespaceParams);
    
// Create eventhub.
var ehParams = new Eventhub() { }; // Customize you eventhub here if you need.
await ehClient.EventHubs.CreateOrUpdateAsync(resourceGroupName, namespaceName, ehName, ehParams);
```

Here is a sample code available for [reference](https://github.com/azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Shared/src/Testing/EventHubScope.cs)

Comment: I think that it is important to note that this cannot be done in the `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs` nor `Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs` client SDKs.  The code referenced is part of our test infrastructure and uses the older management SDK, `Microsoft.Azure.Management.EventHub`.   The samples [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/event-hubs-dotnet-management) may be more helpful and offer additional context.

Comment: Thank you both. Well, we are trying to set up the event hub name in the init container if the event hub name is not found before the application starts. this was the main requirement.

Comment: @JesseSquire thanks for providing the insights! lilan, hope this helped

Comment: It looks like my requirement cannot be archived using `Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs`

Comment: Correct;  You'll need to use a management plane library.  The current management GA package is `Microsoft.Azure.Management.EventHub`.  There is also a preview, `Azure.ResourceManager.EventHubs`,  which offers some improvements to the API surface, most notably a much better auth story,